# Portable GTK cmake project

Tags: c, linux, windows, cmake, gtk

I want to know how I can setup a CMake project that compiles its own GTK in C.I want to be able to compile this project on Linux and Windows. I'm basically wondering how I can include GTK in my project and configure my CMakeList.txt accordingly. Can it be done?

Comment: It's a lot of work, a lot. You surely don't want to do that. GTK has many dependencies, compiling each dependency in turn will require more software to be compiled, the list can become really large very quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory it can be done, in practice it's so complicated that it will take a very long time to setup the build system correctly, and then it will take a lot of time to compile.

Also,

- On Linux, you don't really need to because if you link dynamically to GTK and all the other required libraries then you could build dependency aware packages like *rpm*s or *deb*s or even more peculiar ones like *Arch Linux* or *Slackware* packages.

  You could even create a *gentoo*/*protage* package since, distributing GTK with your software will force your software to be GPL so the source code will have to be available if someone asks for it anyway.
- On Windows, there are binary distributions for GTK that can be redistributed with your software, see [this for example](http://www.geany.org/Download/Releases).

Compiling GTK is a very huge task and requires a lot of knowledge about all the dependencies and how to compile them properly, not to mention it takes a lot of time.

You have to go with something else because this is not only difficult, it's also unnecessary since there are many ways to distribute software that uses GTK.

Comment: You're right, I was thinking about doing something way too overkill. All I want to do actually is present a message box and be able to do it whether my code is compiled on linux or windows. I'll probably just have two function and load the correct one depending on the OS. Thanks for the answer, it really helped me realize what I really need!